# How to classify images based on the amount of colors in the image?

Tags: image-processing, classification, rgb, threshold

I have a problem where all images have the same object; however, these objects can either have number_of_colors<=3 OR number_of_colors>3 and images are not labeled.

My attempt starts by converting RGB to LAB and Consider only the A & B to find the color coverage of that image. I was thinking of it as an area on the AB space.   So for every image, I found the range of A and B (i.e max(A)-min(A), max(B)-min(B)) and multiplied them together to get the area, assuming it's a rectangle. Then I threshold using this feature.

Please let me know if intuition is correct and why it isn't working. Here is the confusion matrix:

- TP:  0.41935483871, FN: 0.0645161290323
- FP: 0.0967741935484, TN: 0.41935483871

#### Here is the basic routine the should work per image

```
    LAB = rgb_to_lab(data_rgb[...,0],data_rgb[...,1],data_rgb[...,2])
    A = LAB[1]
    B = LAB[2]

    minA,maxA = np.min(A),np.max(A)
    minB,maxB = np.min(B),np.max(B)

    diff_A = maxA - minA
    diff_B = maxB - minB

    area = diff_A * diff_B 
    # p is the normalized area
    p = area/(200*200.)
    # Found 0.53 to be the best possible threshold
    if p >0.53:
        print 'class 1 - colors > 3'
    else:
        print 'class 2 - colors <= 3'
```

#### Edit 1:

[Here is an image to show how the threshold separates positive and negative images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu8YD.png)

#### Edit 2:

[This shows the same plot but only considering A and B values with luminance between 16 and 70 which seems to increase the area of separation reduces the FP by 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjuSN.png)

Comment: The number of colors in an image is a fuzzy concept. You need to formalize it.

Comment: 40% correct classification?? thats pretty good - your method is crude

Comment: Well, I have no experience in image processing. I would love to know what is the standard way to do this. I could manually find the range of each color in Hue after converting to HSV but it seems too specific which might not handle all the colors in the test set.

Comment: Lab is fine but I recommend somehow considering lightness for the delta. E.g. the CIEDE2000 formula should get you started and help formalize the "number of colors" concept.

Comment: @SimonThum, thanks for suggesting this. I've tried to threshold the luminance range before taking the min and max. I'll edit my question to include my trial. I'll check the formula!